# Swift generics complex inheritance

Tags: swift, generics, inheritance, compiler-errors

The following Swift code does not compile:

```
class Entity {

}

class EntityConverter<T: Entity> {

}

class GetEntityServerAction<T: Entity, C: EntityConverter<T>> {

}

class GetEntityListServerAction<T: Entity, C: EntityConverter<T>>: GetEntityServerAction<T, C> {

}
```

with the error:

```
Type 'C' does not inherit from 'EntityConverter<T>'
```

for the `GetEntityListServerAction` class definition.
For some reasons the compiler doesn't see that C parameter is defined like inheriting exactly the same type it wants.

The code should look rather simple for those who are used to complicated generic hierarchies in Java or C# but the Swift compiler doesn't like something indeed.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You might find that using protocols and associated types is the more Swift-like way of doing things:

```
class Entity { }

protocol EntityConversionType {
    // guessing when you say conversion, you mean from something?
    typealias FromEntity: Entity
}

class EntityConverter<FromType: Entity>: EntityConversionType {
    typealias FromEntity = FromType
}

class GetEntityServerAction<T: Entity, C: EntityConversionType where C.FromEntity == T> {  }

class GetEntityListServerAction<T: Entity, C: EntityConversionType where C.FromEntity == T>: GetEntityServerAction<T, C> { }

let x = GetEntityListServerAction<Entity, EntityConverter<Entity>>()
```

Possibly `GetEntityServerAction` can also be represented by just a protocol, and that you could convert `Entity`, `EntityConverter` and `GetEntityListServerAction` to structs, also.

Comment: Thank you! That resolves the issue. Even though I don't see any advantages of using protocols instead of class-based approach for this particular case from the code perspective. But maybe I've just not perceived the whole power of associated types yet :)